# Third party rest service returns 503 from mule flow

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have been consuming third party address lookup service from my mulesoft application, this works fine when i execute it in anypoint studio with mule server 3.9.0.

When i deploy the same application to cloud run time manager (3.9.0), I am getting HTTP status 503 (service unavailable).

I tried adding property "anypoint.platform.gatekeeper=false" in cloud runtime properties, but still no luck.

Could anyone please assist what configuration mistake i have done, as i am new to MuleSoft.

```
Message               : Response code 503 mapped as failure.
Element               : /Air-s-address-v1-address-lookup-flow/processors/1 @ Air-s-address-v1-development:Air-s-address-v1-address-lookup.xml:20 (Address Lookup)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
Response code 503 mapped as failure. (org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator.validate(SuccessStatusCodeValidator.java:37)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.validateResponse(DefaultHttpRequester.java:431)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:414)
  (264 more...)

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Below is my HTTP Request configuration:

[image: Http Request configuration]

Comment: Hi Santosh, if you're able to contact the owners of that service I would suggest you do so. A 503 points to an issue on their end (server side), not yours (client side).

Comment: Hi Josh, I tried getting in touch with them, service seems fine as i am able to get the response when i try hitting the service from my local machine. when i deploy the application to mule cloud, its throwing me 503 status.